# How do you use one class for multiple tags?

Tags: html

I want to use one class for two different tags. Do I have to declare it like `<h1 class="line">` and then `<p class="line"`> ??? and in the CSS would it just be `.line` and it would change it for both then? Please help. Thanks

Comment: Add `class="line"` in the tags

Comment: can you show us what you have already?

Comment: Tell me the reason for using same class for h1 and p

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare the class within your CSS:

```
.line {
    background-color: red;
}
```

And then you can apply the class to your HTML elements:

```
<tag1 class="line" />
<tag2 class="line" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy: just use the same class for several different elements. E.g.:

HTML:

```
<div class="line">
    Lorem ipsum...
</div>

<p class="line">
    Blah blah blah
</p>
```

CSS: for example, give each element with the `.line` class a red border:

```
.line {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

See the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hbwa8o22/)!